# Python 'utf-16-le' Error when getting the columns from MS Access Database table

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am getting the following error:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 372-373: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

The code only occurs sometimes, which I don't understand why.  Sometimes the columns print and sometimes I get the error.  what the code is doing is looping through the filepath, grabbing access databases, and then getting the columns that exist for table "mytablename".  the columns do not have any special characters.

```
 filepathlocation = '//testfilepath'
 access_driver = datasources['MS Access Database']


for filename in os.listdir(filepathlocation):
     if filepathlocation.endswith(".mdb"): 

         fullfilepath = os.path.join(filepathlocation, filename)
         accessConn = pyodbc.connect(driver = access_driver, dbq = fullfilepath)
         accessCur = accessILIConn.cursor()

        for row in accessCur.columns(table='myTableName'):
             accesscolumnnames = accesscolumnnames + row.column_name + ';'

        print(accesscolumnnames)
```

I did see in another post where this was used

```
for fld in cursor2.columns(rows.table_name.decode('utf-16-le')):
```

I am not sure how to change my code to follow this.  i tried adding

```
for row in accessCur.columns(table='myTableName'.decode('utf-16-le')):
```

I'm new to python..so i know my syntax is not correct.

So I ended up changing the code to the following and this is working:

```
    sqlColumns = 'SELECT * FROM Mytable where 1=0;'
    res = accessCur.execute(sqlColumns)
    columnlist = [tuple[0] for tuple in res.description]
    columnnames = ';'.join(columnlist) + ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Microsoft Access ODBC driver, documented here:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/328

You can use an output converter function to work around the issue:

```py
def decode_sketchy_utf16(raw_bytes):
    s = raw_bytes.decode("utf-16le", "ignore")
    try:
        n = s.index('\u0000')
        s = s[:n]  # respect null terminator
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s

# ...

prev_converter = cnxn.get_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, decode_sketchy_utf16)
col_info = crsr.columns("Clients").fetchall()
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, prev_converter)  # restore previous behaviour
```